# HTML Even number exception for Specific string

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, python-2.7

Below is the html code I have mentioned even number row  format is different.

But if string "QACheck:" in row. I need to use odd number row format Even it comes in Even number row. Please help

For Even number row I used like below:

```
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

Below is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         
        <style>
        p {
            font-family : Calibri;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-align : left;
        }

        p.fade {
            color : #CCCCCC;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        em  {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            font-weight: lighter ;
        }
        em.pass {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: green ;
        }
        em.fail {
            font-style : italic ;
            font-size : 16px;
            color: red ;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        hr {
            align: left ;
            margin-left: 0px ;
            width: 500px;
            height:1px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr {
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

        th {
            background-color: #cceeff;
            color: black;
            padding: 4px;
            border-right:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        }


        </style>
         
        <body> 
            <table>
<td style='color:Coral'>QACheck: ABC</td>
<tr>
<th>PARA</th>
<th>OT</th>
<th>QA</th>
<th>Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>FruitName</td>
<td>Apple</td>
<td>OK</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:Coral'>QACheck: XYZ</td>
<tr>
<th>PARA</th>
<th>OT</th>
<th>QA</th>
<th>Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>FruitName</td>
<td>Orange</td>
<td>OK</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>VegName</td>
<td> drumstick</td>
<td>OK</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: If you have the ability to change the markup, maybe use a different HTML attribute `<tr data-type="QA">` and style it with `tr[data-type="QA"] { color: #f2f2f2; }`

Comment: Please elaborate more info. I am new to HTML

Comment: your html is wrong. a `td` can't be a direct child of `table` and a `tr` can't be a direct child of a `tr`. It needs to be `table -> tr -> td/th`

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Actually above code is generated from python. I will make corrections in my python program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, you can add [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) that are not rendered on the page, but can be used by Javascript or CSS.

If you use CSS [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) then you can target and style the nodes you want based on those `data-*` attributes.

An example :

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #9999FF; }
tr[data-type="QA"] { color: #ff0000; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-type="QA">
    <td>this is red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This can be combined with regular general rule `nth-child` to acheive the result you want.

If you have several rules that contradict, you can make one more important by appending ´!important` after it :

```
tr[data-type="QA"] { color: #ff0000 !important; }
```

Comment: For some reasons I cannot use table shown in example this red I used in code without table but not working . I just added tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
        tr[data:type="QA"] { color: #ff0000 !important; } in above code not working

Comment: My bad, I had a typo in the CSS, this is `data-type`  (with a "-" not a ":")

Comment: I add this, <tr data-type="QA">
<td style='color:Coral'>QACheck: vNIC</td>
</tr> But not working added and In main program tr[data-type="QA"] { color: #ff0000 !important; }

Comment: But If add table it will work but i dont want to use table <table>
<tr data-type="QA">
<td style='color:Coral'>QACheck: vNIC</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Well, your HTML should be correct first. Normally a `td` goes in a `tr` that goes in a `table`. Your example may show your desired output but is not correct ant may vary in a different browser. Now that you know about the `data-*` element, you can try to work it out.